# obj.property is undefined but when I do the check, it returns false when it should return true

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

i have an object in my database that either has a value or not. When i retrieve the object and evaluate if the property is undefined or not it always evaluates to false.

in this example from my code, obj.MayflyerID is undefined but when I do the check, it returns false when it should return true. both obj.MayflyerID === undefined and obj.MayflyerID !== undefined return false

```
let arrayofMayflyerID:String[] = [];
console.log("MayflyerID 1:"  + arrayofMayflyerID);
console.log("is undefined : "+obj.MayflyerID === undefined);
console.log(obj.MayflyerID !== undefined);      
console.log("is undefined : "+obj.MayflyerID === null);
```

Comment: There's not enough code here for us to help debug. Please edit your question to include the [complete, minimal/standalone code that anyone can run to get the same problem you have](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You may want to check whether the equality semantics of typescript could be the problem.

Comment: @Happy-Monad thanks, i changed the expression from === and !== to  == and != and everything works. Though would this cause any problems in the future?

Comment: As long as the code does what you expect I **guess** it's okay, but please keep in mind I've never done Typescript .